# Comparing set of properties of 2 objects in JS to find out which properties changed and to what?

Tags: javascript, object, properties, compare

I have an object called baseObject. I made a copy of the baseObject but changed any 2 properties.

```
var baseObject = {prop1:1,prop2:2,prop3:3}
var newObject = {prop1:0,prop2:2,prop3:1}
```

As you can see, prop1 and prop 3 changed. So is there any code I can use to return prop1 and prop3 and their new values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return an object which will contain prop having distinct values

```
var objDiff = {};
for (var elm1 in obj1) {
    for(var elm2 in obj2){
       if(elm2.prop1!=elm1.prop1){
         objDiff.prop1 = elm1.prop1;
       }
       if(elm2.prop2!=elm1.prop2){
          objDiff.prop2 = elm1.prop2;
       }
       if(elm2.prop3!=elm1.prop3){
          objDiff.prop3 = elm1.prop3;
       }
    }
}
return objDiff;
```

Comment: here obj1 & obj2 are two objects